# Do WotG and Force still deflect projectile spells?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In Dark Souls 1, the miracles Wrath of the Gods and Force had a nifty extra feature that could be used to deflect most projectile spells. Is this still the case in Dark Souls 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out: No.

I believe the reason for this is due to the addition of shields with the "spell-parry" ability.

Some (not all) of these shields are: [Golden Wing Shield](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Golden+Wing+Shield), [Cleric's Parma](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Cleric%27s+Parma), [Magic Shield](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Magic+Shield), and [Cursed Bone Shield](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Cursed+Bone+Shield). The [King's Mirror](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/King%27s+Mirror) also possesses this ability, and it replaces the two-handed bash.

It is important to note that the phrase "spell-parry" should not be taken literally. All this effect does is deflect and nullify the spell, it does no damage if you manage to deflect it into another entity (friend or foe).